# ListError when mapping Pydantic class to csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, types, casting, pydantic

I am trying to use pydantic classes to represent records of a CSV. Some fields in this CSV represent things like numbers, dates, encoded lists that are better handled as such. So I assign the appropriate type to the coresponding pydantic field and rely on pydantic to cast the string to the type. Unfortunately this fails for lists.

```py
from typing import List
import csv
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: List[str]
    c: str

# Write class to CSV
x = Foo(a=1, b=["hello", "world"], c="foo")

with open("/tmp/test.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=x.dict().keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(x.dict())

# Try to load the class back from CSV
with open("/tmp/test.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    y = Foo(**next(reader))
```

I expect that `y` would be instance with the same values as `x`, but instead it crashes with `ListError`. This code does succeed in outputting `/tmp/test.csv`, and its contents are:

```
a,b,c
1,"['hello', 'world']",foo
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "When I define a Pydantic model with foo: int, and then pass foo="2", it naturally fails." No, no it doesn't. If you annotate it with `foo: int` it will automatically call `int(x)` on whatever your input is, and it shouldn't fail. Can you please provide a [mcve]? if I define a basic `class Foo(pydantic.BaseModel) ....` and just add `foo: int`, then `Foo(foo="2")` correctly parses to `Foo(foo=2)` as one might expect. Are you sure you didn't use `foo: pydantic.StrictInt` ?

Comment: " Is there a more idiomatic way to make it so that if pydantic receives a string instead of the type it wants, it first tries to cast it to that type before giving up and complaining?" IOW, that is exactly what pydantic does out of the box, so you really are going to have to provide details (which really really should always be doing anyway, that is, always provide a [mcve])

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for the clarification - seems like I got confused. In fact I was getting the error for an `List`, not an `int`, and I falsely assumed `int` would have the same problem. Let me update the question.

Comment: OK, so your fundamental problem is that you are trying to store lists in csvs... you can't really do that. You can store *some string*, but then you have to somehow parse that string. Normally, you should use something like `json` and not just use the `str` representation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Let me add a note to the question about that.

Comment: What is `Foo.json()` supposed to be?

Comment: " If I add string fields to my class, Foo.json() will encode those too, which transforms hello to "hello". In the CSV this then becomes """hello""" -- quite ugly." please, show us exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was referring to the `.json()` method that pydantic classes have, which returns a json representation of the object.

Comment: But how would you be using that with a csv writer object? That just returns a JSON `str`.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit the question.

Comment: But look, CSV is fundamentally not the right way to be storing this if you want to make your life easy. At this point, you'd be better off just writing your own way to convert a `Foo` object into an appropriate object to pass to `writer.write`. Of coures you could write a validator that parses the JSON string. But you are going to have to write *something* these tools are not going to work seamlessly together because they aren't really designed to.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If you're just opposed to using CSV to store lists at all, there's not really much to be discussed here as far as the question. I wish you had told me that before making me do all the edits.

Comment: I'm not *opposed* to it but you originally wrote in your question that you wanted to avoid a validator, my point was that you are going to have to do something.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is how I would do what you want to do:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator
import json

class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar: int = None
    baz: List[pydantic.StrictStr] = Field(default_factory=list)

    @validator('baz', pre=True)
    def _maybe_json(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, str):
        
            try:
                return json.loads(v)
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                raise ValueError("not valid JSON") from e
        return v

    def to_csv_row(self):
        row = self.dict()
        row["baz"] = json.dumps(row["baz"])
        return row
```

Note how `StrictStr` handles this:

```
In [4]: Foo(baz='["a"]')
Out[4]: Foo(bar=None, baz=['a'])

In [5]: Foo(baz='[1]')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 Foo(baz='[1]')

File ~/miniconda3/envs/maze-etl/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for Foo
baz -> 0
  str type expected (type=type_error.str)
```

But if you don't want that just use `List[str]`

And just use it like:

```
In [10]: foo = Foo(bar=1, baz=['a','b','c'])

In [11]: foo
Out[11]: Foo(bar=1, baz=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [12]: foo.to_csv_row()
Out[12]: {'bar': 1, 'baz': '["a", "b", "c"]'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to create a validator that checks the value being passed, and if it's a string, tries to eval it to a Python list.

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: List[str]
    c: str

    @validator("b", pre=True)
    def eval_list(cls, val):
        if isinstance(val, List):
            return val
        else:
            return ast.literal_eval(val)
```

This can of course potentially allow people to inject Python code via the CSV, and it is possible to construct lists which cannot be reconstructed from their string representation. In my case, the CSVs are all created by me and the lists are simple lists of string, so this limitation is not a problem.